# How to use css filter on IE

Tags: css, html

How can I use the filter brightness - invert in internet explorer.

This works fine on chrome and firefox but not on interet explorer

```
.imgs {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    filter        : brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

Comment: There is no support for IE or Edge version 12 https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer does not support [css filter](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

However, since you're not doing anything fancy with this filters, just making the images white (I'm guessing your're hiding them with js by adding that class?) you can use a different aproach, like using a container around those images with a white background and just set visibility: hidden on the images.